# BizTalk MSMQ Receive Locations Not receiving. Error details: The Messaging Engine is shutting down

Tags: biztalk, msmq, biztalk-2013

So I have been running into this issue since we set up our BizTalk Server on a new network. We have the same MSMQ settings between the two servers. 
The data stays in our AX MSMQ folders and has the correct permissions.

The system does not ever throw an error until I stop/restart the Receive Host Instances.
(we get one of these errors per message in any of our MSMQ ports)

Full error:

> A message received by adapter "MSMQ" on receive location
>   "recv_loc_file_ax_2012_customer_message" with URI
>   "FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:AXSERVER\AXOUTPPDCUSTOMER" is suspended. Error
>   details: The Messaging Engine is shutting down. MessageId: 
>   {65E24FE1-317E-4636-AFC7-B43FACBDBEDF} InstanceID:
>   {6618EEB3-9B72-4123-BD8C-422661A59BDD}

Then the messages finally appear under suspended instances after this error occurs. I am able to resume them and they all process as expected.
I have looked almost every, Anyone have suggestions for what is causing these messages to not be read into my MSMQ receive ports properly?

EDIT: This BizTalk server is connecting to a remote AX server's MSMQ, but I am doubting this changes anything I have not already looked into.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this a private queue?

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj no the queue is not private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error was on the guys who installed MSMQ on the remote server; the active directory was not set up thus not properly autenticating my BizTalk Server account.
2. Answer for BizTalk: The way to find these hidden errors was by changing the MSMQ BizTalk receive port to a WFC-NetMSMQ.

Other: we are a little baffled that BizTalk was able to take the messages out of MSMQ despite the AD not being set up and "force messages through" but this is a minor detail to note.

[BizTalk reference](http://blogical.se/blogs/johan/archive/2010/04/20/weird-msmq-issue-with-an-even-weirder-solution.aspx)